# UV mapping texture get sliced? in some area

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I have a flat face (created by bisect fill) that I have to unwrap for using with image that must be pixel perfect(no compress or shear).

What I have done are:

1. Select bisect filled face
2. UV>Unwrap it gives me this, notice there are some lighter triangle.

[image: UV unwraped face]

3. And when I applied texture for it I got this (you can ignore gray square in the image)
   [image: What I got after I add texture to it]
   It is supposed to be a smooth gradient texture, but it looks like some part of image is cut or fold somehow.
4. I tried to fix it by using relax tool in blender which remove white triangle from this first image, but, it makes things worse when I apply texture instead.
   [image: no more white triangle]
   [image: worse, not smooth gradient at all!!]

I'm new to blender and may be asking a silly question. I've been struggling on this for 3-4 weeks now, I've searched everywhere, but I can't find any post relate to my issue. I don't know what else to do, so I turn to this community. Please help me.

Updated #1:
I found that we can manipulate mesh.uv using bpy scripting. Is there a way using that?

Comment: Don't use concave polygons. Cut it to smaller convexes or triangulate the face.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that. In addition, I've some experienced with bpy scripting and found that you can manipulate mesh.uv yourself is there a way around this?

Comment: @ FFeller thanks for your suggestion I've tried triangulate face too, however, the problem presist. it is only solved by using smart UV project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I figured it out!

It's turn out that in order to achieve the result I want, I must use smart uv project instead.

I believe that the cause of this problem is that normal unwrap does strech the texture a little, while smart uv project doesn't

Normal unwrap result:

[image: Normal unwrap]

Smart uv project result:

[image: Smart uv project]